# How can I convert from JsonNode to MultiValueMap spring boot (java8)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jsonnode

I have a spring boot project. Form data is posted to me by the client. I get this formData with MultiValueMap. Then I convert it to JsonNode and do something. As the last response, I need to return the JsonNode data I have to the server. How can I convert JsonNode to MultiValueMap?

```
content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

@PostMapping(value = "/tds/init")
public ResponseEntity init(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> paramMap){}
```

example json value:

```
{
field1 : 
"asd"
,
field2 : 
"asdd"
,
field3 : {
field4 : 
"values"
,
field5 : 
"P-256"

},
field6 : 
"123123213"

}
```

Comment: Spring uses jackson to automatically convert your response type to JSON. You simply just return the type in your init method using the diamond operator like so: ResponseEntity<YourType>.

Comment: I want to convert json to MultiValueMap how can I do it?